# How to stop keyboard entry on HTML input='date' to avoid massively out of range dates

Tags: javascript, html

The code:

```
<input type="date">
```

Allows for users to enter any sort of ridiculous dates. For example, a user can set a future date of 01/01/123456
It seems to revert to a max year of 275760 if you try and enter 999999.

I was looking for a way to limit keyboard entry to force users to use the dropdown function to avoid this.

So far, the best I've been able to do is limit the date range of the input using max, which stops the typed year from being able to exceed the same amount of characters as the number of charcters you set for the year you select.

I though about setting this to 3000-01-01 as the max date to keep things under control. This would mean the user could only select from the dropdown dates until that date, but could manually enter the year up to 9999.

```
<input type="date" max='3000-01-01'>
```

Is there a way to lock keyboard entry whilst maintaining dropdown functionality?

Comment: using JS is an option for you or you need some browser-defined way?

Comment: Would prefer it worked across browsers (Noting type=date isn't supported by all browsers). JS is fine, but I still havn't found anything that would help.

Comment: is this input inside some kind of form?

Comment: I'm saving on change using an AJAX call.

Comment: then just add a validation before the ajax call...(https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment (due to limited browser support), but I was looking for a way to see if keyboard input could be restricted for my own and community edification.

Comment: @berto99 the question doesn't mention forms or ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keydown` event and `event.preventDefault()` like so:

```js
document.getElementById('date-input').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<input id='date-input' type='date'>
```

Or better yet, you can use inline HTML:

```html
<input id='date-input' type='date' onkeydown='event.preventDefault()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit the keyboard entry of an input field, you need to override the keydown event with JavaScript.

Assuming it has an I'd of "inp", then in JS

`
inp.onkeydown= e=> {
If (!verify(inp.value)) {
e.preventDefault ()
return false
}
}

function verify (str) {
return parseInt(str) < 3000
}

`